# Getting many-to-many objects populated with Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following Many-To-Many relationship setup illustrated here by a database diagram:
[image]

These are represented by the following POCO classes, from which the database was created using Entity Framework code first:

```
public class ExerciseCategory
{
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
    public Exercise Exercise { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Exercise
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ExerciseCategory> ExerciseCategories  { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ExerciseCategory> ExerciseCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to get all exercises which would include the list of categories they belong to.  Since it is a many-to-many relationship one exercise can have many categories.
I tried the following code:

```
_context.Exercises
            .Include(e => e.ExerciseCategories)
            .OrderBy(e => e.Name).ToList();
```

But it does not populate the properties of ExerciseCategory...

How should I construct my query to get ExerciseCategory's Category property populated?  Preferable in one query and not within a "for" loop, because potentially there will be many exercises displayed on one page and the performance might be an issue.

Comment: check if your lazyloading is enabled in your context

Comment: Doesn't populate any of the properies or just the navigation properties (`Exercise`/`Category`)? Also, use the `virtual` keyword when declaring properties to be lazy loaded. i.e. `public virtual List<ExerciseCategory> ExerciseCategories  { get; set; }`

Comment: @strickt01 Lazy loading is not yet implemented in EF 7 [GitHub issue 3797](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797)

Comment: *it does not populate the properties of ExerciseCategory* What do you mean exactly? Do you see `ExerciseCategory` object with properties not properly loaded, or did you expect to see *Category* properties?

Comment: If I look at the properties in the debugger, the values of Exercise and Category of ExerciseCategory were null.  I completely forgot about lazy loading!  Once I implemented the whole flow and accessed the properties programmatically it did work!  Even without properties being marked as virtual...

Comment: Lazy loading and EF7? Lazy loading and non-virtual properties? I think you're misunderstanding the concept of lazy loading.

Answer (score 5):

Entity Framework 7 many-to-many support is still not complete. Currently you have to map one-to-many relationships manually for your `Exercise` and `Category` entities. Your entity classes are set up correctly. You now need to override `OnModelCreating` method in your DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ExerciseCategory>()
        .HasKey(t => new { t.ExerciseId, t.CategoryId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ExerciseCategory>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.Exercise)
        .WithMany(p => p.ExerciseCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ExerciseId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ExerciseCategory>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.Category)
        .WithMany(t => t.ExerciseCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.CategoryId);
}
```

See [Relationships - Entity Framework 7.0 Documentation](https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many)

Also make sure to include `DbSet<ExerciseCategory>` property in you context.

After this the complete eager query can be constructed in following way:

```
_context.ExerciseCategories.Include(ec => ec.Exercise)
                    .Include(ec => ec.Category)
                    .Select(ec => ec.Exercise)
```

Or by using ThenInclude on Exercise-query:

```
_context.Exercises.Include(e => e.ExerciseCategories)
                  .ThenInclude(ec => ec.Category)
```

Comment: Funny. You're only repeating what the OP already has. They never tried to do it the EF6 way. Now what about this `Include` failure?

Comment: @V.Leon Your first query does not return unique Exercises, but you could add the Distinct() method.  But the problem that ExerciseCategories of each object returned are null and are not lazy loaded. 

The second query works, but it is no different from what I already had.  It looks like it still lazy loads the Category property according to SQL profiler.  I was hoping to load all of the data at once for performance consideration...  Or am I overreacting?

Comment: @WheelBuilder What do you mean by it's no different and what do you mean by lazy loading? Doesn't ThenInclude not load Category-properties? You're right about Distinct in first query and about somewhat non-optimally generated SQL in second query. I profiled the generated SQL, and noticed it surprisingly forms two separate queries (one SELECT for Exercise and other SELECT for Exercise-ExerciseCategory-Category inner join). Unfortunately I'm not certain why the SQL query is formed this way.

Comment: @V.Lean I meant to say that "_context.Exercises.Include(e => e.ExerciseCategories)" **and** "_context.Exercises.Include(e => e.ExerciseCategories).ThenInclude(ec => ec.Category)" produced exact same queries in the profiler...  And categories were lazy loaded on both cases.

Comment: You don't need the OnModelCreating code or the Id's in the join table ef7 will generate that automatically. Your problem is the ThenInclude. Ef7 doesn't support lazy loading yet.